# Merge object Ramda

Tags: javascript, node.js, ramda.js

I am trying to perform um compare merge com ramda of the following values:

```
const data1 = {"crypto1":"BTCUSDT","crypto2":"ADABTC","crypto3":"ETHUPUSDT"};

const data2 = [
  {"symbol":"ETHBTC","baseAsset":"ETH","status":"TRADING","id":1},
  {"symbol":"BTCUSDT","baseAsset":"LTC","status":"TRADING","id":2},
  {"symbol":"ETHUPUSDT","baseAsset":"BNB","status":"TRADING","id":3},
  {"symbol":"NEOBTC","baseAsset":"NEO","status":"TRADING","id":4},
  {"symbol":"ADABTC","baseAsset":"QTUM","status":"TRADING","id":5},
  {"symbol":"EOSETH","baseAsset":"EOS","status":"TRADING","id":6}
];
```

What I need is to do a search for data1 (crypto) and match with data2, the expected result is:

```
result = [
  {"symbol":"BTCUSDT","baseAsset":"LTC","status":"TRADING","id":1},
  {"symbol":"ADABTC","baseAsset":"QTUM","status":"TRADING","id":2},
  {"symbol":"ETHUPUSDT","baseAsset":"BNB","status":"TRADING","id":3}
]
```

It should be noted that the id must change according to the order of the data in the data1 variable

Thanking the support with some recommendation on how I should do it.

Comment: Update your post title: this is filtering, not merging. You're not combining data1 and data2 into a new object. And then search the web/SO based on the fact that you're trying to filter. While bearing in mind that the [documentation for array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#examples) is pretty useful already, and you should definitely read through it because `filter` is a _powerful_ function.

Comment: Is there a strong reason you want to do this in Ramda?  It's simple enough in vanilla js: `Object .values (data1) .flatMap ((crypto) => data2 .filter (({symbol}) => symbol == crypto))`.  I'm one of Ramda's founders and a big fan, but I try to use it only where it offers simplification over vanilla code.  I don't think it does here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `R.indexBy` to create a dictionary of `{ [symbol]: object }`, and then pick the items from the dictionary using `R.props`, after converting the keys (`data1`) to an array using `R.values`:

```js
const { curry, pipe, indexBy, prop, props, values } = R;

const fn = curry((keys, data) => pipe(
  indexBy(prop('symbol')), // index the values by the symbol
  props(values(keys)) // convert the keys to an array and get them from the dictionary
)(data));

const data1 = {"crypto1":"BTCUSDT","crypto2":"ADABTC","crypto3":"ETHUPUSDT"};
const data2 = [{"symbol":"ETHBTC","baseAsset":"ETH","status":"TRADING","id":1},{"symbol":"BTCUSDT","baseAsset":"LTC","status":"TRADING","id":2},{"symbol":"ETHUPUSDT","baseAsset":"BNB","status":"TRADING","id":3},{"symbol":"NEOBTC","baseAsset":"NEO","status":"TRADING","id":4},{"symbol":"ADABTC","baseAsset":"QTUM","status":"TRADING","id":5},{"symbol":"EOSETH","baseAsset":"EOS","status":"TRADING","id":6}];

const result = fn(data1, data2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach would be to :

1. map over the values from data1 - `use R.values`
2. find the object containing that as value against 'symbol' from 'data2' - `use R.find and R.propEq`
3. add indices accordingly - `use R.addIndex`

```
  const R = require('ramda');

  const result = R.addIndex(R.map)((k, idx) => ({
    ...R.find(R.propEq('symbol', k))(data2),
    id: idx+1
  }))(R.values(data1));

  console.log(result);
```